# Wrong scale units when reading raster grib2 in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, scale, units, grib-2

I downloaded grid2 files to read meteorogical variables.

I wanted to read them through QGIS 3.10.2 (windows and I have to stick with this version) but I encountered problems with the scale of the variables. It should be between 0 and around 150, but I have values around 0 and 560,000. There are missing values that are coded as 9999 but those missing values seems to be correctly accounted for when looking into the QGIS metadata of the grib2 files.

I do not have this problem when using QGIS 2.18, and when reading the grib2 file through python (using pygrib package) I still have no problems (values are in the right magnitude).

It seems to be linked to the way I read the file in QGIS 3.

Comment: Can you share the file publically?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the file that I downloaded here: https://dd.meteo.gc.ca/analysis/precip/rdpa/grib2/polar_stereographic/24/

Comment: This issue is _not_ related to QGIS, but rather to the version GDAL, which provides the GRIB2 driver for QGIS. Furthermore, initial investigation seems to indicate the issue is with the input GRIB2 data and not GDAL itself. Investigation is ongoing. Thanks!